# TP-LINK USB Nano Wifi Adapter is too slow

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, command-line, router

I have a TP-Link TL–WN725N Nano USB Wi-Fi adapter. A few days ago, it used to work perfectly. We moved to another house, transferred our desktop PC to our new house. In our new house we put the PC four or 5 meters further from the router than our old house. I actually have a download speed around 50 Mbps, and at the place I put the PC, it goes down to 20 Mbps with a smart phone. With the adapter, however, it goes down to 1.5 Mbps and rises up to 2 Mbps. I tried to some PING tests to the router, and some packages get loss. The connection with the router is stable, but the connection with the Internet itself sometimes goes completely down. I tried the Windows Troubleshooter, reinstalled my drivers, disabling and then enabling the device, plugging off then plugging in the device, and even resetting the router, but none of them seem to work. What should I do?

EDIT: My PC was 0.5 meters away from the router, now it is about 5.5 meters away.

I cannot enter the settings of the router, my ISP blocked that, only they can. I asked them to change my router channel from 11 to 6 (I thought of a signal conflict with my neighbors' routers) and they did. Nothing changes.

Comment: If you are getting packet loss then the connection is not "stable".  The fact that the connection does not immediately drop on one lost packet is not an indication of a "good" connection. Depending on how far away the PC was before and what is between the computer and the router can mean that 5m is actually a pretty big difference.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the latest driver from TP-Link and the previous, one freezes and the other is TOOOOO slow.

The driver I use is from 2015, which is very fast compared to the others.

Here's the link for it.

https://www72.zippyshare.com/v/DXHWAXlW/file.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: How this solves the OP ?

Comment: WN725N drivers caused connection problems for me, so i uploaded the driver for OP as an option to try.